# Bidisperse random close packing of disks algorithm

Tags: computational-physics

I am currently writing an algorithm to generate bidisperse random close packed configurations of disks with the aim of calculating the packing fraction with varying disk concentration $p$ and disk ratio $D$.

The broad outline of the algorithm is as follows:

- Begin with a deterministically disordered nucleus of 6 disks
- Choose the next disk diameter with probability $p$
- Place this disk such it touches the previously placed disk and an appropriate site
- Check for overlaps
- The disk is moved until an appropriate position is found

After the lattice has been built the packing fraction can be calculated.

The algorithm seems to correctly generate random close packed configurations. The issue I am having is that the trend for the packing fraction seems to be incorrect with higher packing fractions for low and high values of $p$. I am calculating the packing fraction using the largest polygon with vertices corresponding to the outer disk edges.

Initially I thought that this could be due to the algorithm inducing crystallization at these extreme values but from inspection of the lattice configurations and cell order distributions this does not seem to be the case.

I have attached figures of how the packing fraction varies with $p$ for $D$=2 and 1000 disks from the algorithm and the expected trend (but for spheres - although the trend is similar). I have also included some of the lattice configurations I generated along with the corresponding packing fraction for 100 disks.

[image: Generated using algorithm]

[image: Expected trend]

[image: Lattice configuration for p=0.1]

Packing fraction for the configuration (p=$0.1$ and $D=2$) was 0.840.

[image: Lattice configuration for p=0.5]

Packing fraction for the configuration (p=$0.5$ and $D=2$) was 0.838.

Why is this trend seen? Is this issue related to the algorithm procedure or a possible bug?